# Moving files into different folders/directories based on their name

Tags: perl, directory

I have a directory or folder consisting of hundreds of files. They are named and arranged alphabatically. I want to move the files into directories or folders according to the first character of their name (i.e. files starting with `a` into one folder, files starting with `r` into another folder, etc).

Is there a way to do it without using [`CPAN`](http://www.cpan.org/) modules?

Comment: What part are you having a problem with? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Why about code from CPAN makes is not ok? Considering I post code to both CPAN and SO, does that means you can't use my code?

Comment: I have done some search and i couldnt find any thing which would help me out in doing the same. I am not sure how to go about this. And i am not able to install any of the CPAN modules. I am asking for help as i am not able to go about with this part of my task. But didnt mean to ask anyone to write the whole code for me. Thank you

Comment: If you're able to use the code we post here, you're able to install modules from CPAN. There's absolutely no difference.

Comment: Cut the attitude. All I asked is what did you need help with, and I was patient about it. (It's been 5 hours and I'm still helping you despite you not having said what you wanted help with yet.)

Comment: @ikegami i am sorry for my behaviour..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are the files all in that one folder, or are they in subfolders? If they are all in a single folder, you can use [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) to access the directory, and then [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) to read the file names and copy them elsewhere (using [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) module's `move` or `copy` function.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use File::Copy;   #Gives you access to the "move" command

use constant {
    FROM_DIR => "the.directory.you.want.to.read",
    TO_DIR   => "the.directory.you want.to.move.the.files.to",
};

#Opens FROM_DIR, ao I can read from it
opendir my $dir, FROM_DIR;

# Loopa through the directory
while (my $file = readdir $dir) {
    next if ($file eq "." or $file eq "..");
    my $from = FROM_DIR . "/" . "$file";
    move $from, TO_DIR;
}
```

This doesn't do exactly what you want, but it should give you the idea. Basically, I'm using `opendir` and `readdir` to read the files in the directory and I'm using `move` to move them to another directory.

I used the `File::Copy` module, but this is included in all Perl distributions, so it's not a *CPAN module* that must be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob()`, or the built-in `File::Find` to build a list of files for each starting letter.